# Apigateway has no routes when deploying AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

My CDK app consists of 4 stacks deployed with --all (dynamoDB, cognito, lambda and apigatewayv2-alpha).

Looks like they're all created correctly, except the API stack... It gets created, but without any routes. I'm creating the API without a custom domain.

```
export class APIStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: APIStackProps, context: CDKContext) {
        super(scope, id, props)

        // Define API Authorizer
        const apiAuthorizer = new HttpLambdaAuthorizer("apiAuthorizer", props.lambdaFunctions["api-authorizer"], {
            authorizerName: `${context.appName}-http-api-authorizer-${context.environment}`,
            responseTypes: [HttpLambdaResponseType.SIMPLE],
        })

        // Define HTTP API
        const httpApi = new HttpApi(this, "httpApi", {
            apiName: `${context.appName}-api-${context.environment}`,
            description: `HTTP API Demo - ${context.environment}`,
            corsPreflight: {
                allowHeaders: ["Authorization", "Content-Type"],
                allowMethods: [CorsHttpMethod.GET, CorsHttpMethod.POST, CorsHttpMethod.OPTIONS, CorsHttpMethod.DELETE, CorsHttpMethod.PATCH],
                allowOrigins: ["*"],
            },
            defaultAuthorizer: apiAuthorizer,
        });

        // get lambda defs
        const lambdaDefinitions = getLambdaDefinitions(context);

        // Loop through lambda definitions and create api routes if any
        for (const lambdaDefinition of lambdaDefinitions) {
            if (lambdaDefinition.api) {
                httpApi.addRoutes({
                    path: lambdaDefinition.api.path,
                    methods: lambdaDefinition.api.methods,
                    integration: new HttpLambdaIntegration(`${lambdaDefinition.name}-integration`, props.lambdaFunctions[lambdaDefinition.name])
                })
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Note that I'm looping through the list returned by getLambdaDefinitions() in other stacks, so it's not that the list is empty.

Here is the code for getLambdaDefinitions:

```
export const getLambdaDefinitions = (context: CDKContext, userPool?:UserPool): LambdaDefinition[] => {
    const environment = {
        DDB_TABLE: `${context.appName}-${context.environment}` 
    }
    const lambdaDefinitions: LambdaDefinition[] = [
       {
        name: "get-users",
        environment,
        api: {
            path: "/users",
            methods: [HttpMethod.GET]
        }
       },
       {
        name: "add-user",
        environment,
        api: {
            path: "/users",
            methods: [HttpMethod.POST]
        }
       },
       {
        name: "delete-user",
        environment,
        api: {
            path: "/users",
            methods: [HttpMethod.DELETE]
        }
       },
       {
        name: "update-user",
        environment,
        api: {
            path: "/users",
            methods: [HttpMethod.PATCH]
        }
       },
       {
        name: "api-authorizer",
        environment: { ...environment, USER_POOL_ID: userPool ? userPool.userPoolId : "UNKNOWN"}
       },
       
    ];
    return lambdaDefinitions;
}
```

Comment: I suggest checking the code synthesized for the template (run `cdk synth`) and making sure that some template code is generated for the routes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay odd... I ran cdk synth as pr suggested by @Victor Smirnov, but got no output (maybe specific to my setup).

I then ran cdk diff api-stack, and then saw the routes... So I ran cdk deploy api-stack and now it works. So I guess CDK deployed the api stack before the lambda-stack...

Thanks :)